# C# Visual Studio 2015 bug?

Tags: c#, console

I'm playing with VS. I'm a rookie, It must be basic. I have created 2 classes and I puzzled with result. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 community edition.

I'm expect to receive at console :

```
myfirstClass
Class
first.
mysecondClass
Class
second.
```

I received :

```
myfirstClass  
Class
```

_

```
    class Program
    {
        public class mysecondClass
        {
            static public string myName ;
            public mysecondClass()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("mysecondClass");
                myName = "Class";
            }
            public static void Display()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myName);
            }
            ~mysecondClass()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("second.");
            }
        }

        public class myfirstClass
        {
            public string myName; 
            public myfirstClass()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("myfirstClass");
                myName = "Class";
            }
            public static void Display()
            {
                myfirstClass d = new Program.myfirstClass();
                Console.WriteLine(d.myName);
            }
            ~myfirstClass()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("first.");
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            myfirstClass.Display();
            mysecondClass.Display();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and write a proper question title

Comment: Also, quit playing with an out of date version of VS when VS 2017 community is free.

Comment: @CDove But there might be even worse bugs! No Sir, I'll keep my VS2012.

Comment: Just note that a) Visual Studio is the development environment. C# is the language compiler that you are suspecting has a bug. b) Whatever bugs there are in the C# compiler are very unlikely to be found by "rookies" to the language.

Comment: both classes are written differently, aside from the difference in text with "first" and "second", so I'm wondering why you expected the results to be the same?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug in Visual Studio. I think you have got two concepts wrongly.

Firstly, the finaliser of a class will not be called immediately after the object is out of scope. It will be called at a random time. It is quite unpredictable.

Therefore, this:

```
Console.WriteLine("first.");
```

is not printed.

The second thing is that constructors of a class is only called when you write `new XXX(...)` (or through reflection). Just calling a `static` method will not invoke the constructor.

In other words, these lines are never executed:

```
Console.WriteLine("mysecondClass");
myName = "Class";
```

You never wrote `new mysecondClass()`.

When this line in the display method of `mysecondClass` executes:

```
Console.WriteLine(myName);
```

Since `myName` has not been assigned, it is null, and so nothing is printed.

Comment: This is only missing the friendly closing call to start learning using the Visual Studio Debugger.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Program
{
    public class mysecondClass
    {
         public string myName { get; set; }
        public mysecondClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("mysecondClass");
            myName = "Class";
        }
        public static void Display()
        {
            var mySecond = new mysecondClass();

            Console.WriteLine(mySecond.myName);

        }

        ~mysecondClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("second.");
        }
    }

    public class myfirstClass
    {
        public string myName { get; set; }
        public myfirstClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("myfirstClass");
            myName = "Class";
        }
        public static void Display()
        {
            myfirstClass d = new myfirstClass();

            Console.WriteLine(d.myName);
        }
        ~myfirstClass()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("first.");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myfirstClass.Display();
        mysecondClass.Display();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

try this